# How to show $h(\mathfrak p)=x$？

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ be a scheme. For $x\in X$, let $\mathfrak m_x$ be the unique maximal ideal of  $\mathcal O_{X,x}$, denote $k(x)=:\mathcal O_{X,x}/\mathfrak m_x$. 
Then $\mathcal O_{X,x}\to k(x)$ induces a morphism $f: \mathrm{Spec}\, k(x)\to \mathrm{Spec} \,\mathcal O_{X,x}$, composite $f$ with the canonical morphism $g:\mathrm{Spec}\, \mathcal O_{X,x} \to X$, we have a morphism $h=gf: \mathrm{Spec} k(x)\to X$.
For the unique point $\mathfrak p \in \mathrm{Spec}\, k(x)$, 
how to show $h(\mathfrak p)=x$？

Answer (score 1):

Choosing an affine neighborhood $U \ni x$, the map $h$ is induced by the ring map

$$\mathcal O_X(U) \to \mathcal O_{X,x} \to k(x).$$

The unique prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $k(x)$ is the zero ideal, i.e. we find $h(\mathfrak p)$ as the kernel of the map above.

Writing $U = \operatorname{Spec} A$ and $x = \mathfrak q \in \operatorname{Spec} A$, the map above is

$$A \to A_{\mathfrak{q}} \to (A/\mathfrak q)_{\mathfrak{q}}$$

with the kernel $\mathfrak q=x$.